# HTML form does not submit correctly

Tags: html, laravel, forms

I am using Laravel for my back end.
This does not work

```
 <form action="/promo/update" style="background-color: #fafafa" method="GET">
```

This works

```
<form action="/promo" style="background-color: #fafafa" method="GET">
```

Is there something about using a GET and an extra "/"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .. *Is there something about using a GET and an extra "/"?*

Short answer? No.

As others have noted, just make sure your routes file is expecting the correct parameters. I'd also suggest reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest) to learn about PUT vs POST, and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing) to learn about form method spoofing.

Generally speaking, an UPDATE endpoint should be a POST or PUT. That's not your question though, so I'll just stick to answering what you have here.

**Routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/promo/update', 'PromoController@update')->name('promo.update');
```

**Blade**

```
<form method="GET" action="/promo/update">
    @csrf <!-- remember to pass your token --> 

    <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" class="form-control" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

**PromoController**

```
public functon update( Request $request )
{
    // Process your data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your route's method (`/promo/update`) is post and you use get...You can see available routes methods just by run below code in terminal:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have made the route in your routes file.

Second...

Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application.

Anytime you define an HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the @csrf Blade directive to generate the token field: